# Como analisar a demora do start de uma aplicação React Native?

Tags: react-native

Tenho notado que está demorando muito tempo para meu APP inicializar (9 segundos) até cair na pagina inicial, isso em release mode (em debug também leva bastante tempo). Durante esse tempo fica uma tela branca.

Tentei usar o profile do flipper mas só consigo fazer análises após o APP estar iniciado então gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de verificar o que pode estar impactando no startup do APP e causando essa tela branca, existe algum recurso ou ferramenta pra isso?

Comment: Difícil saber ao certo, parece ser um problema de ambiente, se não for, vai ser específico ao seu código. É difícil entender por que isso tá acontecendo, pode ser até mesmo o celular que está testando. Seria interessante testar em outros dispositivos com sistemas diferentes para ver se existe algum padrão no que está acontecendo.

Comment: Já foi testado, só tenho interesse em saber mesmo se existe uma forma de analisar isso

Comment: o app faz alguma chamada de api no começo?

Comment: Sim, temos os providers do Keycloack sendo inicializados, tbm do Redux, NativeBase e o React Navigation, fazendo um teste bobo agora, notei que o React Navigation atrasa bastante no start

Comment: Mas pra mim, o React Navigation apenas empilha as rotas declaradas no começo, não deveria fazer "calculos" etc..

Comment: Creio que achei o possível problema, ta num renderItem de uma VirtualizedList. No entanto o mesmo não está na rota inicial e sim em uma das rotas mapeadas no Router, isso que parece estranho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz uma análise "hard coded" e percebi que o motivo da lentidão é por algumas telas que são inicializadas nas rotas utilizarem o faker para alguns mocks:

```
import faker from '@faker-js/faker';
```

Retirando a implementação o tempo de carregamento inicial também diminui.